# Thinkster.io Angularjs tutorial Chapter 3 - Post not added

Tags: angularjs

I have trouble adding a post. It doesn't show up in the list of posts after submitting the form.

My controller is:

```
myapp.controller('PostsCtrl', function ($scope, Post) {
  $scope.posts = [];
  $scope.post = {url: 'http://', title: ''};

  $scope.submitPost = function() {
    Post.save($scope.post, function (ref) {
      $scope.posts[ref.name] = $scope.post;
      $scope.post = {url: 'http://', title: ''};
    });
  };

  $scope.deletePost = function (postId) {
    Post.delete({id: postId}, function () {
      delete $scope.posts[postId];
    });
  };

});
```

Ad the template is:

```
<div ng-repeat="(postId, post) in posts">
  <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
  <a ng-click="deletePost(postId)">delete</a>
</div>
<form ng-submit="submitPost()">
  <input type="text" ng-model="post.title" />
  <input type="text" ng-model="post.url" />
  <input type="submit" value="Add Post" />
</form>
```

The ref.name value is set all right by the Firebase response but it seems it is not a valid type of key for the map of posts.

I wonder what I am missing...

Kind Regards,

Stephane Eybert

Comment: what about debugger? any error?

Comment: I could work around the issue (or is it that I solved it ?) by storing the persistence id as a property $scope.link.id = ref.name; and doing a push as in: $scope.links.push($scope.link); The trouble came from using a map with the persistence id as the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ref.name is a string while you can only use integers in arrays or [ ].

The problem is also mentioned here: 
[Thinkster.io Chapter 3 Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25084279/thinkster-io-chapter-3-issue)