# Thinkster.io Chapter 3 Issue

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to get this tutorial to work:

http://www.thinkster.io/angularjs/S2MxGFCO0B/3-communicating-with-a-server-using-a-service-and-resource

I have started from scratch 3 times. (Deleted the whole Linux VM)  I cannot seem to get this code to pull down what is in firebase.  It saves to firebase perfectly and I can see it, but nothing is displayed.

Code:

/app/views/posts.html:

```
div ng-repeat="(postId, post) in posts">
<a href="{{post.url}}">{{post.title}}</a>
<a ng-click="deletePost(postId)">delete</a>
</div>


<form ng-submit="submitPost()">
<input type ="text" ng-model="post.title" />
<input type ="text" ng-model="post.url" />
<input type ="submit" value="Add Post" />
</form>
```

/app/scripts/controllers/posts.js:

```
'use strict'; 

app.controller('PostsCtrl', function($scope, Post) {
$scope.posts = [];
$scope.post = {url: 'http://', title: ''};

$scope.submitPost = function (){
    Post.save($scope.post, function (ref) {
        $scope.posts[ref.name] = $scope.post;
        $scope.post = {url: 'http://', title: ''};
    });
    $scope.post = {url: 'http://', title: ''};


};

$scope.deletePost = function (postId) {
    Post.delete({id: postId}, function (){
        delete $scope.posts[postId];
    });
};

});
```

/app/scripts/services/post.js:

```
'use strict';

app.factory('Post', function ($resource){
    return $resource('https://xxxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com/posts/:id.json');
});
```

I am fairly confident that the problem is in one of these 3 files.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hey do you still have an account on thinkster ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your code you use an array like a literal object, the ng-repeat directive cant display  the result.

An array index must be an integer and you use a string :

```
Post.save($scope.post, function (ref) {
    $scope.posts[ref.name] = $scope.post;
```

try something like that

```
$scope.posts.push($scope.post);
```

or just declare the $scope.posts variable as a literal object

```
$scope.posts = {};
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: I changed the original declaration in /controllers/posts.js from $scope.posts = []; to $scope.posts = {}; and to an extent it seems that did help.  Now when I add a new post, the delete button comes up, and does actually work. (for any new ones I create).  Where would that first command go?

Comment: the first command could replace the 
        $scope.posts[ref.name] = $scope.post;
in your controllers/posts.js if you dont replaces the array declaration by a literal object

Comment: The second part was key.  It never made mention of switching that.  I also figured out why it wasn't working beyond that.  There was an extra $scope.post = {url: 'http://', title: ''}; set AFTER that so it just kept resetting.  Taking that out has finished fixing my issue.  Thank you so much!